# POSTing data to WebApi after update to 5.1.0 fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have an web app that use webapi for loading / saving data
All used to work ok/
Today I found that there is an updated to ASP.NET MVC / webapi, and I installed the update
But after that POSTing data with jquery no longer works. 
I made no change either in client code or in webapi controller.

My typical POSt statement looks as below:

```
showProgress(true, self.PanelID(), 'Saving...')
j$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: uri,
    data: dataObj,
    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        showProgress(false);
        GLOBAL.setMessage(self, 'Error saving ' + opType + '<br>' + error, true);
    },
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        showProgress(false);
        if (status === 'success') {
        GLOBAL.setMessage(self, opType + " saved ok");
        //....
```

The $.ajax code gets the following error

```
"An error has occurred."

ExceptionMessage
    "This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.Form, Files, InputStream, or BinaryRead has been invoked."

ExceptionType
    "System.Web.HttpException"

StackTrace
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetInputStream(Boolean persistEntityBody, Boolean disableMaxRequestLength) 
at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.GetBufferedInputStream() 
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.SeekableBufferedRequestStream..ctor(HttpRequestBase request) 
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.c__DisplayClass11.b__b() at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.LazyStreamContent.get_StreamContent() at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.LazyStreamContent.CreateContentReadStreamAsync() at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync() at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.d__0`1.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.d__0.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__0.MoveNext()"
```

These are the nuget packages from my solution

```
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage.VB" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.6" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.13" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.18" targetFramework="net45" 
  package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45"
```

Does anyone knows what could be the problem? Any idea on how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Sample controller code:

```
Public Class ImportController
    Inherits ApiController

    
    
    Public Function SaveImportSession(sessid As string,  entity As SIImportSessionDTO) As HttpResponseMessage

        Try
            InspectionData.SaveImportSession(sessid, entity)
            Dim response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            Return response
        Catch ex As HttpResponseException
            Throw
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(Of String)(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Function
```

I'm using only attribute-based routes, and this is my webapi route config

```
Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
            name:="DefaultApi", _
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
```

The problem, my server side code is not even reached, something else on the pipeline throw the exception

Thanks

Comment: could you show what the server side code looks like

Comment: This looks like a bug that we have encountered before...can you please give us the exact repro steps by which you are seeing this...do you have any Web API buffer policy set explicitly? also can you note down the sequence which is causing this...

Comment: Continuing on my previous comment...do you have any route constraints on your routes...i ask this because this was one of the paths which was causing this kind of issue..

Comment: No, I don't have Web API buffer policy set explicitly (I don't know what is that)

Comment: Thanks for the update...From the error it appears that the request stream is being read by other piece of code...Would it be possible for you to give a standalone repro so that we can dig deeper to see the root cause..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem.

My post code uses $.ajax(...), as shown in initial message.

But jquery's .ajax post data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
This worked in previous versions of WebAPI, but in latest update it seems it doesn't accept application/x-www-form-urlencoded by default.

I changed content type to application/json, and I had to convert data to json, and this solved the problem.

So, instead of

```
j$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: uri,
    data: dataObj,
    success: function(...)
```

I had to change to

```
j$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: uri,
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(...)
```

Comment: I am glad you were able to fix the issue...but that's strange...i still suspect there is something else going on...webapi still accepts formurlencoded posts and the exception in your post just doesn't seem to be related to this...would be interested to get a standalone repro of what you were seeing before as it could be a legitimate bug on webapi side..

Comment: Hi, before installing WebApi 2.1 (version no 5.1.0), the code that sent POST data as x-www-form-urlencoded worked just fine. I just passed in the JS object, and left jQuery perform the serialization. But after that update the code stopped working. I posed all significant webapi code, I have no custom filters on anything else on the pipeline.

Comment: I encountered this on a new module I just finished, and first I thought there is wrong with my code. Luckily I got the inspiration to test an old module that I knew it worked, which behaved exactly the same, which made me discover there is not something with my particular code in the new module, but something related to webapi update I just made

Comment: I'm interested to investigate this issue further, if you can give me some guidelines on what to check

Comment: Thanks @bzamfir. From my experience with this issue, the reason behind it could be that the request's stream is read by some other component before it is being read by Web API again. I would really like to take  a look at your application to figure out this issue. Please contact me at kiranchalla@hotmail.com for further discussion on this and if possible I would like to take a look at your whole application's code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be very busy next two weeks with a deadline, but as soon as I finish current tasks, I'll contact you to take a look at the issue.

Comment: Odd I did exactly what you did here but for me it still doesn't work, I get a 404 now.

Answer (score 2):

First clue:

Removing enableCrossAppRedirects="true" from Authentication settings of web.config resolved the issue in my case. Thanks to @kiran-challa

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the fix for this without a work around.

Refer to this thread:
h t t p : / / a s p n e t w e b s t a c k . c o d e p l e x . c o m/discussions/524616

This is a bug in 5.1 - it is resolved in a nightly build
See: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/
and specifically Signed nightly builds:

"Nightly builds can be used with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 or Visual Studio 2012. To use the nightly build:
1.In your Package Manager settings add the following package source:  ....
2.Add or update to the latest build of ASP.NET. The nightly build is labeled  (nightly YYYY MMM DD). "

this fixed the post issues for me (no need to use JSON.stringify anymore) and also fixed multi-part posting for a module that was uploading a file.

Hope this helps someone else!
And hopefully there will be a proper patch for this soon.

Comment: Yip - this build fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

A fix for this issue was published today. Update your packages to the latest (5.1.1) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I am not allowed to comment yet so I have to add an answer.

I have the exact same issue after updating to 5.1.

I was able to get past this error by making a similar change (or actually by specifying the contentType), however, now the controller method receives a null object.

This has affected all POSTS in the app - all previously working.