# Web API 5.1 issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

[POSTing data to WebApi after update to 5.1.0 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322464/posting-data-to-webapi-after-update-to-5-1-0-fails)
Hi!
Do you have any updates on this issue? I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. I'm willing to help as much as I can, because this is a show stopper for me.

Thanks,
-Kirill.

Answer (score 0):

The default formatter seems to be broken really deep in the System.Net.Http, and instead of accepting application/x-www-urlencoded data it only accepts application/json data. Format your data in JSON then post it.